# Is it possible to display Jacoco Coverage report on Jenkins dashboard?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, code-coverage, jacoco

I have jenkins file which has publishHTML method to generate report with .html file of jacoco result. Is it possible to display that report on dashboard like 'Test Trend Result' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I went through a bit then found a solution adding to the pipeline directly

```
publishCoverage adapters: [jacocoAdapter('target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml')]
```

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/code-coverage-api-plugin

Comment: You can also surface everything in one report using the "mergeToOneReport" argument, such as:   publishCoverage adapters: [jacocoAdapter( mergeToOneReport: true, path: '**/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/*.xml')]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [JaCoCo plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco)

> Get coverage data as part of your build First you need to get coverage
>   calculated as part of your build/tests, see the JaCoCo documentation
>   for details. You need at least one or more *.exec file available after
>   tests are executed. Usually this means adjusting your Maven pom.xml or
>   Ant build.xml file..
>
> Set up coverage retrieval and publishing In order to get the coverage
>   data published to Jenkins, you need to add a JaCoCo publisher and
>   configure it so it will find all the necessary information. Use the
>   help provided via the question-mark links for more information.
>   Basically you specify where the *.exec files are, where compiled code
>   can be found and where the corresponding source code is located after
>   the build is finished to let the plugin gather all necessary pieces of
>   information..